# spark NullPointerException when doing collect()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do some testing on my development environment with Spark 2.2 in standalone setup.

I read a csv file using databricks library then I create temp view.
After I run a select statement using `spark.sql()`.
If I do `collect()` on that DataFrame or any other later operation that requires spawning executors, I receive `NullPointerException`.

I use the spark-shell BTW.

this is the code I use:

```
val dir = "Downloads/data.csv"
val da = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(dir)
da.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

val product = spark.sql("select product from data where length(product) >0")

product.collect()
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 3]17/09/03 03:36:34 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$convert(UnivocityParser.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.parse(UnivocityParser.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/09/03 03:36:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$convert(UnivocityParser.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.parse(UnivocityParser.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/09/03 03:36:35 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/09/03 03:36:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$convert(UnivocityParser.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.parse(UnivocityParser.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2390)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$convert(UnivocityParser.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.parse(UnivocityParser.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$parseIterator$1.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:312)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: example of input file (the best - one line on which the problem repeats)

Comment: Any blank lines in the file?  I believe the univocity parser will return null if you try to parse a blank line.  It could also be trying to parse a double or something but the field is empty (null).  Hard to track down the problem without an example input though.

Comment: Spark2 does not require Databricks library

Comment: Does it throw the same error when you use an absolute path rather than a relative one?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that SQL conditions that compare the result of LENGTH() to zero will not work if the column is NULL.

Please try below

```
val product = spark.sql("select product from data where length(product) > 0 and product IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
val da = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(dir);
```